# JFileChooser with confirmation dialog

Tags: java, swing, confirmation

I am working on a program that loads and saves data from text files, and I am asking the user a file name with JFileChooser on load and save.

This question is about the **save** dialog: `new JFileChooser().showSaveDialog();`. The user then could overwrite an existing file without any warning, and that **would be a problem**.

Any suggestion on how to fix this? I have been looking for some method or option, but I didn't found anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I found another workaround, overriding the approveSelection() of the JFileChooser, this way:

```
JFileChooser example = new JFileChooser(){
    @Override
    public void approveSelection(){
        File f = getSelectedFile();
        if(f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG){
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"The file exists, overwrite?","Existing file",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
            switch(result){
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                    super.approveSelection();
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                    cancelSelection();
                    return;
            }
        }
        super.approveSelection();
    }        
}
```

I hope this could be useful for someone else.

Comment: Helped me out! I did the same thing you did but i was having trouble getting the dialog to close after a user chose an option. The "super.approveSelection()" helped me out. Thanks

Comment: For showSaveDialog, you should handle selected file's extension.

Answer (score 7):

As AvrDragon said, closing with X is not handled. I added a default case to handle all unrelevant options:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7919427933588163126L;

        public void approveSelection() {
            File f = getSelectedFile();
            if (f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                        "The file exists, overwrite?", "Existing file",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                switch (result) {
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                    super.approveSelection();
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                    cancelSelection();
                    return;
                default:
                    return;
                }
            }
            super.approveSelection();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Check before saving if the same file already exist then ask user for confirmation does she really want to override :p

```
 JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to override existing file?", "Confirm",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("No button clicked");
    } else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("Yes button clicked");
    } else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("JOptionPane closed");
    }
```

[here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJOptionPanetopromptuserconfirmationademo.htm) is code

To check file already exist use

```
boolean exists = (new File("filename")).exists();
if (exists) {
    // File or directory exists
} else {
    // File or directory does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could verify that the file does not already exists, and even give the JFileChooser a [`FileSystemView`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) (see [this constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#JFileChooser(javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView)))

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this based on your own answer. Posted in case someone else finds it useful:

```
final JFileChooser exportFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
exportFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
exportFileChooser.setApproveButtonText("Export");

final JButton exportButton = new JButton("Export text file");
exportButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int returnVal = exportFileChooser.showSaveDialog(exportButton
                .getParent());

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File outputFile = exportFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (outputFileIsValid(outputFile)) {
                exportFile(outputFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean outputFileIsValid(File outputFile) {
        boolean fileIsValid = false;
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    exportButton.getParent(),
                    "File exists, overwrite?", "File exists",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
            switch (result) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                fileIsValid = true;
                break;
            default:
                fileIsValid = false;
            }
        } else {
            fileIsValid = true;
        }
        return fileIsValid;
    }
});
```