# java file chooser that forces the file to already exist

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

After a bit of googling I'm not seeing this turn up much.  Is there some "generic" way to forces the user to select a file that "already exists"

I could add something like 
http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.help/2004-01/0302.html or like [JFileChooser with confirmation dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651494/jfilechooser-with-confirmation-dialog) but is there some canonical way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want an "Open" behavior, but a confirmation button that says "Save" instead of "Open".

You can do this via this method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String%29

Pass in "Save" for the approveButtonText argument.

Comment: Using the setDialogTitle method would allow you to add a hint like the string in Eng.Fouad's answer, but keep the save button label as "Save" using the showDialog method I linked to above.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setDialogTitle%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

First you need to check if your better option is choser.showOpenDialog or showSaveDialog

Save Dialog will let you select any name in the specified path it could be a non existent file, but open will always accept the selected file.. and you can safely add a file.exists() to ensure the file exists. You can also change the text of the buttons.. dialog.. etc..

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setApproveButtonText("Save");
    int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File selection = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        //verify if file exists
        if(selection.exists()){
            //you can continue the code here or call the next method or just use !exists and behavior for wrong file
        }else{
            //System.exit(0), show alert.. etc
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as this:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
while(true)
{
    if(fc.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION &&
      !fc.getSelectedFile().exists())
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must select an existing file!");
    else break;
}
```